# Select option from Array

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I am working on a side project and to make it easier for managment since almost all of out server names are 15 charactors long I started to look for an RDP managment option but none that I liked; so I started to write one and I am down to only one issue, what do I do to manage if the user types not enough for a search so two servers will match the Query. I think I will have to put it in an array and then let them select the server they meant. Here is what I have so far

```
function Connect-RDP
{

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ComputerName,
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential
)

# take each computername and process it individually
$ComputerName | ForEach-Object{
    Try
    {
        $Computer = $_
        $ConnectionDNS = Get-ADComputer -server "DomainController:1234" -ldapfilter "(name=$computer)" -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSHostName
        $ConnectionSearchDNS = Get-ADComputer -server "DomainController:1234" -ldapfilter "(name=*$computer*)" | Select -Exp DNSHostName            
        Write-host $ConnectionDNS
        Write-host $ConnectionSearchDNS
        if ($ConnectionDNS){
        #mstsc.exe /v ($ConnectionDNS) /f
        }Else{
        #mstsc.exe /v ($ConnectionSearchDNS) /f
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Could not locate computer '$Computer' in AD." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
}
```

Basically I am looking for a way to manage if a user types *server1*

that it will ask does he want to connect to *Server10 or Server11* since both of them match the filter.

Comment: Any help? https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-Item-V-10-beta-5e579fa6

Comment: You might benefit from Ambiguous Name Resolution here: `Get-ADComputer -LdapFilter "(ANR=$Computer)" | Select -Exp DNSHostName`

Comment: @mjolinor I like the way this looks, and since you were the one that wrote it how would you reccomend to use it?

Comment: Nevermind I got it figured out and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another option for presenting choices to the user is `Out-GridView`, with the `-OutPutMode` switch.

Borrowing from Matt's example:

```
$selection = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Directory

If($selection.Count -gt 1){
   $IDX = 0
   $(foreach ($item in $selection){
   $item | select @{l='IDX';e={$IDX}},Name
   $IDX++}) |
   Out-GridView -Title 'Select one or more folders to use' -OutputMode Multiple |
   foreach { $selection[$_.IDX] }
 }

 else {$Selection}
```

This example allows for selection of multiple folders, but can you can limit them to a single folder by simply switching `-OutPutMode` to Single

Comment: Ah yes. Always forget about Out-GridView. Much more user friendly.

Comment: Oooo I've never used -outputmode on Gridview, thats excellent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure what [mjolinor has](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Select-Item-V-10-beta-5e579fa6) it great. I just wanted to show another approach using [PromptForChoice](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx). In the following example we take the results from `Get-ChildItem` and if there is more than one we build a collection of choices. The user would select one and then that object would be passed to the next step.

```psh
$selection = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Directory

If($selection.Count -gt 1){
    $title = "Folder Selection"
    $message = "Which folder would you like to use?"

    # Build the choices menu
    $choices = @()
    For($index = 0; $index -lt $selection.Count; $index++){
        $choices += New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription ($selection[$index]).Name, ($selection[$index]).FullName
    }

    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]$choices
    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

    $selection = $selection[$result]
}

$selection
```

`-Directory` requires PowerShell v3 but you are using 4 so you would be good.

In ISE it would look like this:

[image: ISE Choice]

In standard console you would see something like this

[image: Console Choice]

As of now you would have to type the whole folder name to select the choice in the prompt. It is hard to get a unique value across multiple choices for the shortcut also called the accelerator key. Think of it as a way to be sure they make the correct choice!

Comment: I like the way this looks, so I would just pipe the output of get-adobject to this?

Comment: @Luke Yes. However you would have to make other minor changes to that an appropriate property appears for the buttons/choices. It's the first parameter after `ChoiceDescription`

Comment: Note, however, that this approach will get messy if you have more than a few options to choose from.