# PowerShell Dynamic menu from array

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic, menu

Friends.

Probably a really nice easy one.

On this technet thread 'BigTeddy' wrote a wonderful little script to get a dynamic menu from a Get-Service query.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/74c34d41-1cf6-494e-8fe2-13827c3b7a4d/create-dynamic-menu-system-with-powershell?forum=ITCG

I'm doing something similar and would like to know how to list both the Name and Status in the menu.

Here's the code:

```
$processes = Get-Process
$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $processes.count; $i++) 
{ Write-Host "$i. $($processes[$i-1].name)"
$menu.Add($i,($processes[$i-1].name)) }

[int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
$selection = $menu.Item($ans) ; Get-Process $selection
```

Is that something that can easily be achieved? I'm somewhere around a basic user for PowerShell and so can't figure out where, if anywhere, to put the .Status

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select option from Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479553/select-option-from-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have gotten a reply or figured this one out?

Switched get-process to get-service

```
$services = Get-Service
$menu = @{}
for ($i=1;$i -le $services.count; $i++) 
{ Write-Host "$i. $($services[$i-1].name),$($services[$i-1].status)" 
$menu.Add($i,($services[$i-1].name))}

[int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
$selection = $menu.Item($ans) ; Get-Service $selection
```

Answer (score 1):

For others looking for this post, I was having some issues with

```
$selection = $menu.Item($ans)
```

If you need other properties of the original array / collection try

```
$selection = $services[$ans-1]
```

Then you can access

```
$selection.DisplayName
$selection.StartMode
```

etc