# Powershell script to delete Microsoft Team

Tags: arrays, powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-7.0

I am working on a script to remove a Microsoft team in a tenant using remove-team. How would I go about putting the output of get-team into menu options for the user to choose which team to delete?

Would I need to put all of the teams in an array with just selecting the ObjectID which remove-team needS? i have started off with the below. i can enter $teams[0,1] and it does show the first two teams.

i would like the user to have menu options like below.

1. Team1
2. Team2
3. Team3

Please enter the number of the team you would like to delete

```
$teams = Get-Team
foreach ( $team in $teams) { 
  
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what ya got so far? I don't have those cmdlets available for me so it's hard to help. Besides updating your code in the post, can you also show an example of what the expected output should be?

Comment: it isn't much but i added it. @AbrahamZinala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `for` loop to iterate through the collection of Teams assigning a number to their corresponding index number:

```
$Teams = Get-Team

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Teams.Count; $i++)
{
    "{0}: {1}" -f $i, $Teams[$i].DisplayName
}

# multiple can be selected if comman seperated
$Selection = (Read-Host -Prompt "Select Team(s) to remove").Split(',').Trim()

foreach ($number in $Selection) 
{
    $Teams[$number]
    #Remove-Team -GroupId $Teams[$number].GroupID 
}

<# Output
0: TeamsOne
1: TeamsTwo
#>
```

All that's left to do is prompt for the number of teams to remove and re-select it using the index number.

- Used the `-f` *string format* operator as it should allow you to assign the current iteration of `$i` to the *choice* number, and the Display Name of the teams; giving it a feel of choice selection.
- Using the `.Split()` method let's you make a multiple choice selection given that it's separated by a comma.
- Finally, use a `foreach` loop to iterate through the numbers input into our `Read-Host` assigned to `$selection`. Which gives you the same index number that will be used to select our choice from `$Teams`.

---

Disclaimer: *I don't have teams installed on my machine so I went based off using some pictures from google results, and the MSDocs on the cmdlets.*

Comment: that worked. I was actually in the process of reading through this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705021/powershell-dynamic-menu-from-array. can you explain to me what the $i is?

Comment: @Derek, `$i`, is just the variable that has the current index number of `$teams` assigned. So, if you have 3 teams in `$Teams`, when you iterate through an array, you start off with 0 since arrays start with a 0-based index. So, `$i` increases for each object in that loop; i.e.: `$i = 0`, then `$i = 1`, `$i = 2` and so on...but, since `$teams` only has 3 objects output, and given that array start at 0, the results are just 0,1,2 (*which is in fact 3*). You can also have the selection display at 1 and so on, but that's something you can search up on;)