# How do I avoid double commenting a line in an .ini file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get and modify content for an .ini file, however I need to be sure that the text that I'm looking for is not preceded with a semicolon, which would specify that the line is "commented out".

The .ini file contains a block of parameters, and the block that isn't used is commented out, as below.

```
;   use the following 2 settings for Sierra external GPS  
;GPSType=Sierra  
;Interface=PPP  
;   use the following 3 settings for internal NMEA GPS  
GPSType=NMEA  
Interface=Serial  
Com=4
```

I've tried an If statement in my pipeline, however this would not be be allowed.

```
   $EOF = {
     Write-Host "Ending Program"
     break
   }
Write-Host "test Application Internal/External Modem Selector"     -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
Write-Host
Write-Host "*** Please ensure test is not running ***" -ForegroundColor     Yellow
Write-Host
if (!(Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini"))
  {
Write-Host "Warning - test.INI not present" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red |
Return(0)
  }
Write-Host
Write-Host "1.  Convert for Internal modem (COM4)"
write-Host "4.  Convert for External modem"
Write-Host "Q.  Exit"
Write-Host
$menuresponse = Read-Host 'Choose the option >'
if ($menuresponse -eq "q") {
&$EOF
  }
elseif ($menuresponse -eq "1") 
  {
(Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini") |
  If (($_).notcontains(';Com'))
  {
   {
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'GPSType=Sierra' , ';GPSType=Sierra' } |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Interface=PPP' , ';Interface=PPP' } |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ';GPSType=NMEA' , 'GPSType=NMEA' } |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ';Interface=Serial' , 'Interface=Serial' } |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ';Com=.*' , 'Com=4' } |
    Set-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini"
   }
  else
   { 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Com=.*' , 'Com=4'
    Set-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini"
   }
  }
   }}
elseif ($menuresponse -eq "4") 
  {
   (Get-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini") |
 If (($_).notcontains(';Com'))
 {
  { 
   ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ';GPSType=Sierra' , 'GPSType=Sierra' } |
   ForEach-Object {$_ -replace ';Interface=PPP' , 'Interface=PPP' } |
   ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'GPSType=NMEA' , ';GPSType=NMEA' } |
   ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Interface=Serial' , ';Interface=Serial' } |
   ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Com=.*' , ';Com=6' } |
   Set-Content "C:\Program Files (x86)\Rogers\test\test.ini"
  }
  else
   { 
    Write-Host "Modem already set to External"
    &$EOF
   }
  }
  }
else
{ write-host "Invalid Choice"
}
  Break
```

Is there a way to ensure that I don't end up "double commenting" a parameter in the .ini file, by recognizing whether it had a semicolon preceding it before the instruction is passed?

Comment: try using a regular expression with an `^` anchor as first argument to `replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to be sure that the text that I'm looking for is not preceded with a semicolon

Since you are already using regex why not use the start of string anchor ^ in your matches

```
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '^GPSType=Sierra' , ';$0' } |
```

That would replace GPSType=Sierra but only if it at the starting of the line. If the line already looks like ;GPSType=Sierra it will not match

Note the use of `$0` in the replacement. It represents the whole match string. Using that can help prevent the double up typing.

---

- You should really look into [PowerShell's choice system](https://www.petri.com/more-choices-powershell). Super easy to implement and a more object oriented approach. [Here is an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482033/3829407) that implements it
- You can chain `-replace` so you don't need multiple `foreach-object`: `'123' -replace '1','One' -replace '2','Two' -replace '3','Three'`